# Right cursor position between MathJax formulas

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I have some trouble with inserting `MathJax` formulas. I want that user can insert cursor between each formulas and therefore can `insert` formula between them.

My code:

```
function get(elem) 
{
    currentFormul = elem;
    var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(elem)[0];
    var input = document.getElementById("MathInput");
    input.value = math.originalText;
}
function input()
{
    sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
    var input = document.getElementById("MathInput");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.contentEditable="false";
    span.addEventListener('click', function() { get(this); }, true);
    span.innerHTML = "\\("+input.value+"\\)";
    range.insertNode(span); 
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
}  
</script>
   <body contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"> 
        <span contenteditable="false">
            <button onclick="change()">Change!</button>
            <input id="MathInput" size="60" />
            <button onclick="input()">INPUT!</button>
            <button onclick="someChanges()">FONT!</button>
        </span>   
        <p>S</p>
        <span onclick="get(this)" contentEditable="false">\(\color{red}{x=ax^2}\)</span>
        <span onclick="get(this)" contentEditable="false">\(x=ax^2\)</span>
        <span onclick="get(this)" contentEditable="false">\(x=ax^2\)</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i can't insert `cursor` between formula for new elements, but can for old.
Can someone tell me how do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `white spaces` between the `spans` in your `html`. These white spaces are in fact text node that are child of `body`, which has `contenteditable` set to `true`. So when you click on one of these text nodes, you click in a contenteditable node, hence you get a cursor.

When you add `spans` dynamically, it adds it without white space. There's a text node created, but it's empty so you can't click it.

One easy way to fix this would be to set the `text node` before your newly inserted `spans` to `" "`. It'll then have the same behavior as your old elements. Like this:

```
function input()
{
    sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
    var input = document.getElementById("MathInput");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.contentEditable="false";
    span.addEventListener('click', function() { get(this); }, true);
    span.innerHTML = "\\("+input.value+"\\)";
    range.insertNode(span); 
    span.previousSibling.textContent = " ";
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ox20a7oj/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if i delete the space between formulas then i can't insert cursor between them in next time. How to fix it?

Comment: I'm actually suggesting you add a space between your new formulas. In your question you say it works for old element, but not the new. The reason is because of this whitespace. If it's the behavior you want, then add a space between your new and old formulas.